# Error in third-party SPICE subckt of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, spice

I am simulating my circuit having a `DMG1012T` N-Channel MOSFET in `LTSPICE XVII`. My Circuit is given below:

[image]

However, after downloading the spice model of the MOSFET from [this](https://www.diodes.com/spice/download/1739/DMG1012T.spice.txt) link and putting it in my schematics, the SPICE Software (`LTSPICE XVII`) shows this error

[image]

I tried to open symbol of mosfet included in standard library and found it's pins have been named `D`, `G` and `S`. I am not sure where is the problem and couldn't resolve it now. Please help.

Comment: As far as I know, DIodes doesn't provide LTSpice models. You should try their model in the tool it's designed to work with before you say there's an "error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line

```
.SUBCKT DMG1012T   D=10 G=20 S=30
```

to

```
.SUBCKT DMG1012T   10 20 30
```

Worked for me:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Replace `D=10 G=20 S=30` with simply `1 2 3` and it should work. Renaming to `D G S` should also work, but not in the symbol, it's the definition you're interested in. The `=` is not allowed in subcircuit names or pins in LTspice.

Comment: Changing to `1 2 3` in the `subckt` statement line won't change the pin numbers in the definition? I think then I have to change the definition of the subckt as well. Am I right?

Comment: @abhiarora You're right, forgot to mention that. `10 20 30` is the fastest way to correct, unless you really want other labels. Avoid `=` in their namings, though. Even if you name the subcircuit with some `=` in there, you may see the naming in the element properties, but it will fail to run. That's because the parser, when it meets an equal, it tries to apply evaluation, and unles you really have some boolean expression that can be evaluated (pin names, or node labels in general, only), it won't work, since one equal means assignment of value.